# How to unpack incomplete structs

Tags: python, struct

A common method to make file formats extensible is to include the size of records included in the file in order to make it possible in the future to add more fields to the record.

Now assume that the field has been updated and we have a python `struct` format for the new record layout, but this means that this format cannot be used to unpack records of the older format as the record is too small.

What I would want is for `struct.unpack` to unpack those fields it can unpack (without running out of data) instead of throwing exception.

Is there an easy way to get this done? Or would one be required to have the struct format for each prior version of record layout?

Comment: The `struct` format is intimately tied to the actual format of the file, so yes, such changes to a file's format are backwards incompatible with code to parse them.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any [native feature for `struct`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html) allowing for some backward compatibility.

That means, if you have an exception, you need to fallback to:

- reading the same file with the old `struct`
- marshalling that old struct into a new struct.